# Using Property value of Node1 as a label name of Node2

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 2.1.2 Community Edition.

I have a node called Labelled as **Company** and it's properties are as below:

```
id   : 101
Name : Company
```

Also i have more node which is a child node of Company with a relationship `:Active` . I want this child node label-name should derive from the ParentNode. That is the parent `Name` property should act as a label for it's Child Node.

My Child node looks like as below:

```
Id  : 101
Name: Flipkart
```

How can i achieve this through Cypher query. How can i pass the Property of one node to act as a Label of another node ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Cypher alone. In addition, this is what relationships are for - connecting nodes. The parent name property is only one relationship away from the child. The sort of thing you are trying to do goes against the graph database concept somewhat.

Comment: Are you trying to update second node label?

Comment: Actually I'm not trying to update the second node label. In fact I'm deriving the 2nd node label from the 1st node property name.

Comment: @Jim Biard, How this goes against the graph database concept. Can you please explain this. Is it really not possible to achieve this?

Comment: @shree11, It's not that it isn't possible, but it's not possible with Cypher alone. It goes against the concept (as I understand it) because you appear to be trying to use labels to represent relationships. Why not just use the relationships?

Comment: @Jim Biard, thank you for your suggestion. Here I'm not trying to use labels to represent relationships. Here i'm trying to use the property value of PARENT node to represent the label of its CHILD node. For example if i have 2 nodes P and C where P is parent and C is Child node. parent node looks like this --> `(P:Master{id:201,Name:Group})` . Child node looks like this --> (C:Group {id:201, grpName:"Devices"}). In the above example the Child's label `Group` should come dynamically from Parent's property called as `Name:Group`. Hope the scenario is clear. Can i acheive this in cypher ?

Comment: You cannot do this using Cypher alone. Labels were not intended to be dynamic in this fashion. And this is exactly the sort of thing I'm saying goes against the graph database concept. Instead of using a label on the child like this, use a relationship. You can make the name a property on the relationship if you like. You seem to be approaching this with a 'relational database' mindset.

Comment: @Jim Biard, Yes i understand what you are saying about but my scenario is different.In the above query i did not explained my whole scenario where i would be needing this requiremnt. I will explain my scenario , please let me know whether my approch to acheive that is proper or not. I would like to have suggestion from you as well. I have explained my scenario in the below :

Comment: Scenario :Actually i'm trying to track the history details using the masternode. In my child node i will be having id & 
name field and taking the label name name fron the master node. My master node is having properties called as Id and Name 
field. This Name field should act as my child label name. Here my master and child node is connected by `flag=Y`.
So in future if i want to change existing lable name to someother name,i will create one more masternode with the Name 
peoperty to the new name. (continued in the below comment)

Comment: So in future if i want to change existing lable name to someother name,i will create one more masternode with the Name 
peoperty to the new name. 

so that the relationship between new masternode and chile name is `flag=Y` and the old master 
node and child relationship type should become `flag=N`. Also i will be having careted_date and end_date as relationship 
properties. So doing all this will not let me to change the label name of the child node. only creating new master node 
with proper flag will serve the purpose.

Comment: So that if i want to see the history label name i can query based on the flag and 
creatd_date& end_date. I'm i going for the right approach? or do you suggest any other approch to serve this purpose. please let me 
know if you need more clarity on the scenario.